# If page parent equals ID (number)?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an if statement that is checking the ID of the page, using the following:

```
<?php if ( is_page(10) ) { ?>
```

How can I do something like if page parent is 10?

Comment: Could you give us some more information on the concept of an 'id' in your question?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try something like this

```
global $post;

if ($post->post_parent == 10) {
   echo "parent's id is 10";
}
```

Comment: how would I amend this to include several page IDs e.g. if($post->post_parent == 10,11,12)

Comment: @Adrian, use in_array

Answer (score 2):

```
$id = wp_get_post_parent_id( get_the_id() );
```

Now `$id` has parent page id

Answer (score 0):

Get the current page object, then get its parent ID:

```
global $wp_query;

$currentPage = get_page($wp_query->get_queried_object_id());

if (is_page($currentPage['post_parent'])) {

}
```